# Verb + With/Of/From + noun

Tags: word-choice, prepositional-verbs

Is there any grammatical difference between prepositions in the following word combinations?

> Die from/of laughter, collapse with/from remorse, make haste from/(out) of necessity

or is it purely a collocation thing and each verb should be memorised alongside prepositions that go with it?

Comment: Sometimes definitions overlap enough that either will work; sometimes not.

Answer (score 1):

> Die from laughter

> Die of laughter

> Collapse with remorse

> Collapse from remorse

^ All of these are OK and the first of both pairs means almost exactly the same as the second.

> make haste out of necessity

^ This is awkward, though it would be understood.  Perhaps try instead:

> make haste as needed

Finally,

> make haste from necessity

is completely incorrect use of the preposition 'from'.  When "make" and "from" colocate, the indication is that the object that appears before "from" is being produced from the object after it; the second thing is being turned into the first.

> Make bread from flour.

> Make wine from grapes.

> Make a mountain out of a molehill.